# ImageMagick not converting JPEGs

Tags: imagemagick

I had a problem with ImageMagick not converting JPEGs on a fresh install of Mac OSX Lion. I was getting the fallowing error:

```
convert: unable to open module file `/Users/natewade/.magick/jpeg.la': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/813.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `test1.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: no images defined `test1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

However conversions with gifs and other formats worked fine. After Googling around I came across many people with the same problem online from as far back as 2006. But none of them had  posted a solutions.

When you configured Image magic you may notice this:

```
checking for JPEG... 
checking jconfig.h usability... no
checking jconfig.h presence... no
checking for jconfig.h... no
checking jerror.h usability... no
checking jerror.h presence... no
checking for jerror.h... no
checking jmorecfg.h usability... no
checking jmorecfg.h presence... no
checking for jmorecfg.h... no
checking jpeglib.h usability... no
checking jpeglib.h presence... no
checking for jpeglib.h... no
checking for jpeg_read_header in -ljpeg... no
checking for JPEG library is version 6b or later... no
checking if JPEG package is complete... no
```

Comment: The solution should be in the answer, not in the question. (I've edited both for you.) Also, this is more appropriate for superuser.com, since it's not a programming question.

Comment: Hi Keith, I put it here because while searching for a fix, stackoverflow came up in the search results most, and there was never a solution posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has been solved. This error was on Mac OSX 10.7.3, but after Googling the problem I have found the same problem posted by other versions of OSX as well as other operating systems (seems like CentOS the most). The same fix should apply to other Linux flavors as well.

The problem was quite simple to fix. All you need to do is install Libjpeg:

```
curl -O http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
$ cd jpeg-8c/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Reinstall ImageMagick and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is hitting me as well; I'm using homebrew on OS X Lion, I have jpeg 8d and imagemagick 6.7.7-6 installed, but on some (not all) JPEGs I get the "convert: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3032." error.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu. Same fix, Ubuntu-style: sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev

Comment: After installing this I had to change this line in my ~/.profile from this: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"` to this: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"`

Answer (score 5):

had to install ghostscript - so for mac

```
brew install ghostscript

brew link --overwrite ghostscript

brew reinstall imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have specific header files of JPEG library,
in other words to have installed several *-devel packages like libjpeg-turbo-devel, openjpeg-devel. The same for another image formats like PNG, TIFF, WMF and so on (libpng-devel, libtiff-devel, libwmf-devel, ghostscript-devel, etc).